# Value Error while feeding in Neural Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have programmed a multi-layer neural network but I'm getting an error while feeding my dimension into it. I'm getting a Value Error.

Here is The Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn import preprocessing


# In[207]:

df =pd.read_csv("train_data.csv")


# In[252]:

target = df["target"]
feat=df.drop(['target','connection_id'],axis=1)
target[189]


# In[209]:

len(feature.columns)



# In[210]:

logs_path="Server_attack"


# In[211]:

#Hyperparameters
batch_size=100
learning_rate=0.5
training_epochs=10


# In[244]:

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,41])
Y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,3])
lr=tf.placeholder(tf.float32)


# In[245]:

#5Layer Neural Network
L=200
M=100
N=60
O=30


# In[257]:

#Weights and Biases
W1=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([41,L],stddev=0.1))
B1=tf.Variable(tf.ones([L]))
W2=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([L,M],stddev=0.1))
B2=tf.Variable(tf.ones([M]))
W3=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([M,N],stddev=0.1))
B3=tf.Variable(tf.ones([N]))
W4=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([N,O],stddev=0.1))
B4=tf.Variable(tf.ones([O]))
W5=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([O,3],stddev=0.1))
B5=tf.Variable(tf.ones([3]))               



# In[247]:

Y1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X,W1)+B1)
Y2=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y1,W2)+B2)
Y3=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y2,W3)+B3)
Y4=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y3,W4)+B4)
Ylogits=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(Y4,W5)+B5)
Y=tf.nn.softmax(Ylogits)


# In[216]:

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=Ylogits,labels=Y_)
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)


# In[217]:

correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(Y,1),tf.argmax(Y_,1))
accuracy=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))


# In[218]:

train_step=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cross_entropy)


# In[219]:

#TensorBoard Parameters
tf.summary.scalar("cost",cross_entropy)
tf.summary.scalar("accuracy",accuracy)
summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()


# In[220]:

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess=tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


# In[253]:

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path,graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        batch_count=int(len(feature)/batch_size)
        for i in range(batch_count):


            batch_x,batch_y=feature.iloc[i, :].values.tolist(),target[i]

            _,summary = sess.run([train_step,summary_op],
                                 {X:batch_x,Y:batch_y,learning_rate:0.001}
                                )
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (41,) for Tensor 'Placeholder_24:0', which has shape '(?, 41)'
```

I need to reshape I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, you just have to reshape your input values in order to make them compatible with the placeholder's shape.

Your placeholder has shape `(?,41)` that means any batch size, with 41 values. Your input is, instead, with a shape of `41`.

It's clear that the batch dimension is missing. Just add a 1 dimension to your input and you'll be fine:

```
batch_x = np.expand_dims(np.array(feature.iloc[i, :].values.tolist()), axis=0)
```

Note that probably you have to add a 1 dimension to your `batch_y` variable too. (for the same reason described above)

Comment: Yes ,I 'm facing issue for batch_y now : ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1,) for Tensor 'Softmax_13:0', which has shape '(41, 3).I Tried to expand same way as you guided but resulted into error'

Comment: I tried making similar change :                                                             
batch_y = np.expand_dims(np.array(target[i]),axis=0) resulting to above error

Comment: Your label is a single value, a scalar value in 0, 1, 2, isn't it? You need to one hot encode it first, in order to get a tensor with shape `3`. Then you have to extract a single value from the `target[i]` array to use the right (and single) label for the one same you feed into the network. However, you could ask a new question for this second problem.

Comment: Sir I one hot encoded it But i don't know to retrieve it  and get the tensor in shape.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068683/feeding-labels-with-one-hot-encoded-vectors-in-neural-network

Answer (score 0):

Your data format is incompatible with the placeholder defined as

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,41])
```

It is probably easier to reformat your data which you feed during training/evaluation.  I don't see where you import it but you are going to need to either reshape or swap axes so that it has format (index, 41) and not (41, index)